# is it ok to call (click) in the component tags rather than inside the component itself?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular and i have an excersice where i need to execute a (click) function whenever someone clicks on a component. My question is if is it ok to take this approach:

**recipe-list.html component:**

```
<app-recipe-item 
    *ngFor="let recipeElement of recipes"
    [recipe]="recipeElement"
    (click)="loadDetails(recipeElement)" <!-- here is the function -->
></app-recipe-item>
```

**recipe-list.ts**

```
// some code and stuff..

loadDetails(recipe: Recipe) {
    // some functionality
}
```

so the click function does something directly in the recipe-list.ts, or should i do this other solution which places the (click) function inside the component itself, and then emits an event, and captures it in the recipe-list.ts to do what I need to do:

**recipe-list component:**

```
<app-recipe-item 
    *ngFor="let recipeElement of recipes"
    [recipe]="recipeElement"
    (recipeDetails)="loadDetails($event)" <!-- im expecting an event... -->
></app-recipe-item>
```

**recipe-item.html component**

```
<a 
    href="#" 
    class="list-group-item clearfix" 
    (click)="loadDetails(recipeElement)" <!-- here is the function -->
    >
    <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.name}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recipe.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <span class="pull-right">
        <img 
        [src]="recipe.imagePath"
        alt="{{ recipe.name }}" 
        class="img-responsive" 
        style="max-height:50px;">
    </span>
</a>
```

**recipe-item.ts**

```
// some imports and some other stuff

@Output() recipeDetails = new EventEmitter<Recipe>();

loadDetails(recipeElement: Recipe){
    this.recipeDetails.emit(recipeElement); // I emit the event when the click function fires
}
```

**recipe-list.ts**

```
// some code and stuff..

loadDetails(recipe: Recipe) {
    // some functionality
}
```

Both solutions works, i just want to know if the first one is a bad practice or is acceptable (i know there are better ways to do this, but right now this are the tools i have in the course to solve this challenge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially: it depends.
You can use a component as a page in site or you can use it as one of topics. So if you use like site you can put both in one component. If you would like to separate you can move to another component.